# Quartz.Net retrieve object from scheduler before stopping it

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm working on a C# project that use Quartz Scheduler. In this project there is a simple form. On this form there is a button that i use to create a scheduler and a trigger, and then to start a job.

```
private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IScheduler firstScheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
    firstScheduler.Start();

    IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<AcquireLogsJob>()
    .WithIdentity("acquireLogsJobId", "acquireLogsGroupId")
    .Build();
    jobDetail.JobDataMap.Add("reader", readerToUse);

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("acquireLogsTriggerId")
        .StartNow()
        .ForJob(jobDetail)
        .WithCronSchedule("0 0/" + sampleTime.Value + " * * * ?")
        .Build();

    firstScheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
}
```

I send to the job a param with name reader. I stop the job shutting down the scheduler, with another button.

```
private void stopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (firstScheduler != null)
    {
        firstScheduler.Shutdown(true);
    }
}
```

Whereas the param i passed to jobdetail needs to be closed, my need is: or before shutting down the scheduler i want to retrieve the object reader that i passed to job, or in alternative the job notices the shutting down and close it the reader. 
How i can do that? Thx

Comment: I'd suggest you just close the reader in stopBtn_Click as it seems you have it instance variable anyway. Either give total control of opening and closing to job or handle it outside.

Answer (score 0):

before Shutdown(true) method.

retrieve all the job and find the job you put reader

or

define Schedulerlistener class to implement ISchedulerListenr interface

retrieve jobs in SchedulerShuttingdown() method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply, i follow the way of ScheduleListener that implement ISchedulerListener interface,  then i add my scheduler to listener with

```
scheduler.ListenerManager.AddSchedulerListener(mySchedListener);
```

and all worked fine.

:)